# HTTP Request error using Alamofire

Tags: swift

I am trying to access my MAMP database webservice using Alamofire. Following is my code:

*Following is my router to construct my URL:*

```
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
    static let baseURLString = "http://pushchat.local:44447/"
    case PostJoinRequest(String,String,String,String,String)
    var URLRequest: NSURLRequest {
        let (path: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]) = {
            switch self {
            case .PostJoinRequest (let addPath, let userID, let token, let nickName, let secretCode):
                let params = ["cmd": "join", "user_id": "\(userID)", "token": "\(token)", "name": "\(nickName)",  "code": "\(secretCode)"]
                return (addPath, params)
            }
            }()
        let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString)
        let URLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: URL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))
        let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL
        return encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
    }
}
```

*Following is my viewdidload code:*

```
Alamofire.request(.POST,Router.PostJoinRequest("api.php","12345678901234","12345678901234","ABCDEF","TopSecret")).responseJSON()
            {(request, response, JSON, error) in
                println(JSON)
            }
```

*Following is the compile error:*
Cannot invoke 'responseJSON' with an argument list of type '((*,*,*,*)->_)'

*Following is the declaration from Almofire for your reference.*

```
:param: method The HTTP method.
:param: URLString The URL string.
:param: parameters The parameters. `nil` by default.
:param: encoding The parameter encoding. `.URL` by default.
:returns: The created request.
    */
//        public func request(method: Method, _ URLString: URLStringConvertible, parameters: [String: AnyObject]? = nil, encoding: ParameterEncoding = .URL) -> Request {
//            return request(encoding.encode(URLRequest(method, URLString), parameters: parameters).0)
//        }
```

Please let me know why am I facing this issue while chaining and what is it that I am not doing right?

Thanks for your help.
Dev

Comment: I'm no expert with Swift, but it looks like you've got the wrong syntax in the second code block.

Comment: the second and third argument had default value so I believe its not mandatory to pass those. I have also tried to add those but no luck.

Comment: If you look up sample code calling that function online, you will see that they have their curly braces in a different place than you do.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error message is really misleading – there is no problem with `responseJSON` but with `request` method itself.

In fact compiler does not like your second parameter. You are passing `URLRequestConvertible` but `URLStringConvertible` is expected (see the signature you posted).

Maybe you wanted to call another version of `request` method:

```
    //:param: URLRequest The URL request
    //:returns: The created request.
    public func request(URLRequest: URLRequestConvertible) -> Request
```

In that case you have to adjust your `Router` class and set HTTP method into `NSURLRequest` created inside. For example:

```
    let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))
    URLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"
```

Note you will also probably need to use another parameter/data encoding.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't think Alamofire has data/parameter encoding for POST method after my research from last 2 days. Correct me if I am wrong. In which case I am left with option: Alamofire.request(<#method: Method#>, <#URLString: URLStringConvertible#>, parameters: <#[String : AnyObject]?#>, encoding: <#ParameterEncoding#>). Please correct me if I am wrong and if there is more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: In Alamofire parameters you pass to POST request are used to construct HTTP body and I think there is no _really simple_ way to use them in query string as you want. So you can 1) change your API to read parameters from HTTP body or 2) build the URL you need in some another way and use it for POST request. Eg. using you your original code: `let path = Router.PostJoinRequest("api.php","12345678901234","12345678901234","ABCDEF","TopSecret").URLRequest.URLString` and then `Alamofire.request(.POST, path).responseJSON()`.

Comment: I figured out a way which seems to work(please see the code I pasted in my original post) and it seems to create record in my database via PHP web service.